# Physical meaning of Russell–Saunders and $jj$ coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, interactions, orbitals

In the case of Russell–Saunders coupling (LS coupling), the total $L$ and total $S$ are coupled to a total $J$. In the case of $jj$ coupling, first, all the individual $j = l + s$ values are formed, and then all $j$ values are summed up to form the total $J$. Both coupling schemes eventually end with $J$ as a good quantum number. So, what makes these schemes differentiate from each other?

What is the physical meaning here? In the case of LS coupling, is the interaction between all individual s among each other and all l among each other dominant? If so, why aren’t L and S good quantum numbers respectively? Why do they have to be coupled to $J$?